# How to insert count or % in ggplot on y axis when using factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a chart, where on the x-axis I show a range of dates and on the y-axis a stacked bar that shows the number (or percentage) of cases for this day (2 categories).

For example: On 01-01-2010 I have 3 cases, (2x yes, 1x no). For me to have an overview of how many cases we are talking about, I would like ggplot to show the scale ranging from 1-3 on the y-axis the numbers  rather than "yes"/"no".

I looked through the ggplot cheat sheet and the only thing that deals with the y axis is scale_y_discrete(), but this does not really change anything.

```
s <- c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", 
       "2010-01-02", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-02")
g <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No")

s <- strftime(s, "%D")

df <- data.frame(s,g)
df$g <- factor(df$g)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = s, y = g, fill=g)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  labs(x = "Date",
       y = "Answer",
       title = "Sample")][1]][1]
```

I can produce the chart but I do not know how to replace the factor levels with the scale (number of cases: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) on the y-axis.
What option within ggplot is it that I do not see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histograms:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=s)) + geom_histogram(stat="count")
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=s, color=g)) + geom_histogram(stat="count", fill="white", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I just added position="stack" to have a stacked chart.